# React: passing data from child to parent after processing

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to pass data up several levels of child -> parent and do something with that data at each stage without creating new functions at each level? For example, if I have three levels of component:

**PARENT**

```
function Parent() {
    const parentFunction = (str) => {
            console.log('Output processed by parent', str)
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Child onClick={parentFunction} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**CHILD**

```
function Child({passedFunc}) {

    // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THE RESULT OF ONCLICK BEFORE PASSINT IT UP
    // TO PARENT

    return (
        <div>
            <GrandChild onClick={passedFunc} label="first" />
            <GrandChild onClick={passedFunc} label="second" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**GRANDCHILD**

```
function GrandChild({passedFunc, label}) {

    const handle_click = () => {
        passedFunk(label + 'something');
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handle_click}>{label}</div>

    );
}
```

When the `grandchild` is clicked a string is passed up two levels to `parent` where it is printed to console. But I also want to be able to do something with that data at the first  `child` level before it is passed up and still printed.

Comment: At some point you might want to create a more global state via context, redux, zustand or whatever and then any component can set state and any component can subscribe to that state and re-render accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like this

```
function Child({ onClick }) {
  const [saved, setSaved] = useState(null);
  const handleGrandchildClick = async (grandchildParam) => {
    await sendToSomeServer(grandchildParam);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (saved) {
      // do something with saved
      console.log("Saved:", saved);
    }
  }, [saved]);

  return (
    <div>
      <GrandChild
        onClick={async (grandchildParam) => {
          // set state to trigger using useEffect
          setSaved(grandchildParam);

          // do something right in this callback function
          await handleGrandchildClick(grandchildParam);

          onClick(grandchildParam);
        }}
        label="first"
      />
      <GrandChild onClick={onClick} label="second" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but in general you can intercept value of the callback at any layer. But when it becomes too deep, there are several ways to handle it and one of the is to use context ([docs](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)).

Comment: 1. Does it intercept the value and stop its propagation? What I want is to intercept but still pass the value up. 2. Does it have to be async? 3. Would you recommend doing this or going straight to useContext?

Comment: 1. No, whether to propagate or not is on you, notice `onClick(grandchildParam);` is called at the last line in the callback function. That `onClick` is a function originated in Parent and passed to Children as `onClick` prop (in your example, you renamed to `passedFunc` which is incorrect)

2. No, just an example that I add async function in there. It is up to you how you want to handle it.

3. It depends on your use case. I can't really recommend without knowing the context. If props drilling still works for you, go for it. Performance can almost always be improved later.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const handleParent = (num) => {
    console.log(num); // 101
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Parent
      <Child onClickParent={handleParent} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ onClickParent }) => {
  const handleChild = (num) => {
    onClickParent(num + 100);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Child
      <GrandChild onClickChild={handleChild} />
    </div>
  );
};

const GrandChild = ({ onClickChild }) => {
  const handle_click = () => {
    onClickChild(1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      GrandChild
      <button onClick={handle_click}>button</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you remove the  `onClick` event in the child? How does the click even get monitored then?